# Add a "page break indicator" to an endless RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, inflate

I have an endless RecyclerView that basically loads new data when the user scrolls to the bottom. It adds a null object to the end of the list (to represents the ProgressBar) and deletes that object when the execution is complete. Now I want to inflate a view to indicate the "page break" after loading new batch of data. It looks like this:

[image]

However, the position of the objects in the list will be messed up if I add a null object to represent the view break. Is there any way to achieve this without touching the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html).  You can use this to add visual cues above/below `View` objects being shown by your `RecyclerView`.  Note that it gets called for each `View` object, so you'll have to determine which objects get the page break before (or after) them and only draw it for those objects.

Comment: Good answer. Would be curious to see a very basic example. Is it really neccessary to use the drawXXX-Methods from the canvas object to add a visual clue or is it possible to inflate some objects and add them?

Comment: In fact I'm using `ItemDecoration` to draw divider between the items. And yes, the hard thing is to know when to draw the page break.

Comment: @viertausend unfortunately, yes, you have to draw.  That being said, you can inflate a view hierarchy but just not attach it to anything and have it draw into the canvas appropriately.

Comment: @haint agreed...it's tough to know exactly where the page ends as `RecyclerView` will pre-load views and each Android device can have different screen geometry.  It sounds like you're on the right track, though!